# AsyncDisplayKit calculateLayoutThatFits() function works in 1 project, not in another

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, asyncdisplaykit

I'm doing this asyncDisplayKit tutorial for a collection view of images.

http://www.tekramer.com/improving-uicollectionview-uitableview-scrolling-performance-with-asyncdisplaykit/

I can run the finished project and everything works fine.  I copied all the code exactly the same into another project which I am combining multiple tutorials. For some reason I get 1 error.  This is odd since it includes every file and I copied and pasted them all perfectly.  This is where I get the error:

```
override func calculateLayoutThatFits(constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayout {
        return ASLayout(layoutableObject: self, size: nodeSize)
    }
```

The error says that the layout arguments should be layout and position, but if I change it then it can't use self as the layout.  Anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**

Please try this. This function works for my project.

```
override func calculateLayoutThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayout {
   return ASLayout(layoutableObject: self, constrainedSizeRange: ASSizeRangeMake(nodeSize, nodeSize), size: nodeSize)
}
```